# Can I execute system commands in Windows 8.1 apps?

Tags: windows-runtime, command, windows-8.1

I'm developing an app for Windows 8.1 ( WinRT ) and
I'm trying to execute a cmd command like -let's say- `notepad`, but I can't find a way. I search all over the internet and couldn't find anything about it. In one or two pages, there was writing `You cannot execute a command`, but actually, I don't want to believe that.

So is there REALLY NO WAY I can execute a command?

Comment: It wouldn't be much of a sandbox if you could escape it that easily!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29

Comment: Basically, much like Apple's App Store, there is supposed to be a limit to how much damage a malicious (or just plain badly written) program can do.  The merits of any particular technical approach to achieving this are debatable and way out of scope here, but that's why you can't just run an arbitrary command.

Comment: sorry to hear that.. I was really hoping that I could run a command. Anyways, thank you for clearing this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is NO WAY you can execute a cmd command.